# VMWare Fusion: How do I combine muliple numbered vmdk files into a -flat.vmdk file?

Tags: virtualization, vmware, virtualbox, vmware-fusion

I'm on Mac 10.6.6 using VM Ware Fusion 3.1.2.  I created a Windows 7 image, but when I examine the files that make up the image, there are 21 "extent" files -- e.g. files with names like

Windows 7-s001.vmdk
Windows 7-s002.vmdk
Windows 7-s003.vmdk
...

Ultimately I want to convert this to something that an be used by VirtualBox, and so to do that, I need to get a single vmdk (-flat.vmdk) file.  Does anyone know how to generate a single file given the multiple files I have now?

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Virtual Machine - Settings - Hard Disk -> Uncheck "Split into 2GB files" and press Apply :)

Comment: FYI: This feature is not in VMware Workstation 11.1

Answer (score 8):

For those who (like I did) may end up here looking for how to do this on ESXi (CLI): There is no `vmware-vdiskmanager`. Instead, use `vmkfstools`:

```
vmkfstools --clonevirtualdisk source.vmdk dest.vmdk
```

Answer (score 6):

I have also had success doing this using the command line.  Kind of heavy lifting, though - one has to RTFM and Google search carefully to find the right incantations.

look in

```
/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmware-vdiskmanager
```

see -r for the "convert" option

Comment: Yep. A similar thing can be done on Windows too (you can find the Disk Manager tool in `C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Workstation`). More information about the available command line options can be found [here](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/disks_vdiskmanager_run_ws.html).

Comment: Full command: vmware-vdiskmanager.exe –r thefirstfile.vmdk –t 0 singlefile.vmdk You can find vmware-vdiskmanager in the folder mentioned above.  Credit goes to http://www.mahmoudthoughts.com/2009/07/merge-2gb-vmdk-files-to-one-single-vmdk.html for the command.  After you combine it, you'll need to point your VM at the new disk.